# Redirection to another portlet with ActionMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portlet, response.redirect

I am using Liferay and Spring MVC and I want to redirect to another portlet and pass it a parameter, but when I try to set render parameters I get this error:

> 15:20:24,859 ERROR [portal-web.docroot.html.portal.render_portlet_jsp] (http-foo-10.23.243.3-8080-7) **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Set render parameter has already been called**
>
> at com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl.sendRedirect(ActionResponseImpl.java:48)
> at sk.foo.showcasePortlet.ShowcaseController.redirect(ShowcaseController.java:65)

The showcaseController's method which is being resolved contains just the assignement and the redirect:

```
@ActionMapping(params = { "action=redirect" })
public void redirect(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) 
    throws IOException {

    response.setRenderParameter("path", request.getParameter("path"));
    response.sendRedirect("/path/to/portlet");
}
```

Why can't I assign that parameter? When I remove the line the redirection works, but the problem is that the portlet which the user is being redirected to expects a string parameter "path":

```
@RenderMapping
public String barBaz(RenderRequest request, @RequestParam String path){
    // ...
    return "some/jsp";
}
```

How can I pass the parameter to the `barBaz` method in another portlet, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exception says this **IllegalStateException: Set render parameter has already been called**

Be aware that this interceptor is calling setRenderParameter on the ActionResponse, which means that you cannot call sendRedirect in your handler when using this interceptor. If you need to do external redirects then you will either need to forward the mapping parameter manually or write a different interceptor to handle this for you

[DOC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/portlet.html)

Comment: what if I pass it with response.setProperty("path", "somePath") will the other portlet be able to recieve it with request.getProperty("path")? (if it's not a @RequestParam)

Comment: No you can't do this well actually properties can be used by portlets to provide vendor specific information to the portal. These vary to Portal server vendor. The Easy way to use session. request.getSession(). on session object you can set attributes.                                   session.setAttribute("portletscopeattribute", "portletscopevalue", PortletSession.PORTLET_SCOPE); Also you can use Events.

Comment: I'll use session then. Thanks a lot!